# Full/Infinite Set in Python

Tags: python

i really can't found anything about this, the idea is this, the intersection of any alement with it returns the element:

```
val == val & InfiniteFullSet
True
```

The Full/Infinite set the idea is "simulate" all elements.

And a note, the set can contain anything, can be a set of tuples, or Ints, etc.

If python don't have any set to to this, how can i do something like this?

Comment: It would be pretty trivial to write a class with the `&` operator overloaded to just return the other element.  Just implement `def __and__(self, other): return other`

Comment: Hi, i don't think is always trivial, an example, if i want intersect a list of sets, i need a start point, so we can use this type of set there.

Comment: This is exactly the answer that you accepted as correct, though...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class InfiniteFullSet(object):

    def __and__(self, item):
        return item

    def __rand__(self,item):
        return item



my_set = InfiniteFullSet()
val = 3
print(val == val & my_set)
True
```

Comment: `InfiniteFullSet` would need to be an *instance* of such a class for the OP's code to work. You also need to define `__rand__` in your class, or else it only works when the universe is the left operand of `&`.

Comment: so, in python there is not a set for this, but this is a very nice way to do this!